# XSL Failed to compile stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt

I am having trouble figuring out why I keep getting the error "Failed to compile stlyesheet" when I try to run my program. I am assuming that it is an error in my stylesheet but I cannot seem to find it.

I am probably just looking over it but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you! The xsl can be found below.

---

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/> 
   <xsl:template match="/"> 
 <PhoneBook> 
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </PhoneBook>
  </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="AddressEntry">
<Entry>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Name"/> 
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Address"/> 
</Entry>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Name">
<Name>
<xsl:apply-templates select="LastName"/>, 
<xsl:apply-templates select="FirstName"/> 
</Name>
</xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="Address">
<LocatorInfo>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="PostalAddress/Street"/> 
  <xsl:apply-templates select="PostalAddress/City"/> 
 <xsl:apply-templates select="PostalAddress/PostalCode"/>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="Phone"/>
 </LocatorInfo>
 </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="FirstName"> 
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
<xsl:value-of select="."/> 
</xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="LastName">
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have your `version` specified twice in your `xsl:stylesheet` tag. Correcting this allows it to compile.

---

As a side note, if you don't have a program that will compile or validate your XSL you can always run it through Java using the following command

```
java com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.cmdline.Compile test.xsl
```

It will attempt to compile your XSL and display any syntax errors at that time. It's great for troubleshooting things like this when you don't have a proper tool.

Comment: +1, though xsltc will only work for XSLT 1.0 (it's not clear from the question whether the OP intended to use 1.0 or 2.0, though the current stylesheet doesn't use anything 2.0-specific).

Comment: Wow thank you very much, I guess I need more Coffee this morning, should have seen that. And thank you for the advice I will use that in the future for sure.

Answer (score 5):

You've been told why your stylesheet is invalid, but you need to address the deeper problem: how come you weren't seeing the error messages?

I don't know if you're using Saxon, but the symptoms suggest you might be. If you try to compile a stylesheet from within a Java or .NET application, the compilation error messages will by default be written to the System.err output stream. In many contexts, for example in an application run within a web server or even a desktop GUI, the contents of System.err might not appear on your screen, so it is important to direct the output somewhere where you can find it (with a web application, at least during developent, I often write the error messages into the HTML response page). There's a variety of mechanisms in the API to achieve this, for example by writing your own ErrorListener - the details depend on which API you are using.

Alternatively, develop and debug your stylesheets using a development environment such as oXygen or Stylus Studio which is designed for the purpose.

Comment: This was the crucial tip for me - adding my own error listener. Thanks!

Comment: This helped me. The actual errors from the compilation was hidden away in a property, which I needed to look at.

Answer (score 2):

It is not compiling because you have two 'version' attributes in the 'xsl:stylesheet' element. Resulting in an ill-formed (non-XML) document.

In XML an element node cannot have two attribute nodes with the same name.